# Superoptimization - gcc

Tags: optimization

Apparently gcc supports [superoptimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superoptimization), What are the flags necessary to enable it in gcc/g++? Is there really such a thing?

Comment: Are you asking about [GNU Superopt](http://directory.fsf.org/wiki/Superopt) ? It does exist, although it seems to have been last updated 20 years ago...

Comment: Err, no. GCC does not support superoptimization, and the GNU Superoptimizer was never mainlined within GCC. However, some of the sequences it found apparently were integrated into the GCC peephole optimizer's wisdom repository, as a `grep` of the source code reveals.

Comment: @Memo yes. How does it work can it be integrated into a makefile